# How do I open the debug window in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vscode-debugger

I've accidentally closed that debug window (with the table that shows all the values). How do I reopen it? (I have been seriously trying for about 20 minutes and couldn't find it)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the window with 'Watches'?

Start a debug session and have the program halt on a breakpoint.
Under 'Debug' menu select 'Windows'
Select 'Locals', 'Autos', 'Watch (and then 'Watch1').